# UMDH/Windbg not compatible DMP file?

Tags: windbg, umdh

I'm using UMDH 6.1.7659 out of the latest Windows Debugging Kit.  I'm wanting to try and generate a dmp file that I can look at in WINDBG to investigate a memory leak in an unmanaged 64-bit C++ EXE:

```
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=<.PDB_file_directory>
umdh -p:<valid PID> -f:c:\temp\dump1.dmp
```

When I try and open up the DMP file in WinDbg (Version 1607), I see this:

```
Loading Dump File [c:\temp\dump1.dmp]
Could not match Dump File signature - invalid file format
Could not open dump file [c:\temp\dump1.dmp], Win32 error 0n87
"The parameter is incorrect."
**** DebugClient cannot open DumpFile - error 80070057
```

DUMPCHK on the same DMP file gave me the same result.

Is UMDH not compatible with WINDBG anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got some misunderstanding,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak

UMDH generates its own data format (a text based data structure), which is clearly not process dump files for WinDbg to analyze.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I just assumed 'dmp' files meant user dmp files.